# Forms: 2nd text box not clearing when first is cleared

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I am just starting some minor scripting due to losing a program at work and having to convert everything in PDF format. Currently the form I'm working on has 2 pages that need to be identical but I am having issues getting the 2nd page text boxes to clear when I have nothing in the first pages boxes. I am using the following script in the first box:

```
//Set the vars one and two:
      var one = this.getField("Text1");
      var two = this.getField("Text2");

      //next check if two is blank and if so, populate it with one’s value
      if(two.value==''||two.value==null){two.value=one.value}
```

Text 1 is page 1 box, text 2 is page 2 identical box, I only have the script posted in the page one box on blur so when you click out it copies to page 2. But when you clear text 1, text 2 doesn't clear. Any help would be appreciated as I am very noobish with scripting still.

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a function (event listener)? Post more code.

Comment: That is the whole code segment, on blur run a javascript set to text box 1 so that it copies text to box 2.

Comment: on blur of what? The form?

Comment: Each individual text box, there are approx. 50 boxes on page 1 of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = this.getField("Text1");
var two = this.getField("Text2");

// if one's text is empty then empty two's text as well
if(one.value==''|| one.value==null){two.value='';}
// if one's text is not empty then check if two's is empty to fill it with one's text
else if(two.value==''|| two.value==null){two.value=one.value;}
```

Comment: @Jesse but if two's text is not empty and one's text is not empty, two's text won't get filled with one's text. Right? That's what I understood.